# Заполнение SQL таблицы

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

Помогите составить запрос.

Есть таблица `Car_Owner`, состоящая из полей `id`, `id_car`, `id_owner`, таблица `Cars (id, name)`, таблица `Owner (id, name)`.

Нужно заполнить таблицу `Output (id, car_name, owner_name)`. Как это можно сделать одним запросом, и возможно ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Output (id, car_name, owner_name) 
SELECT co.id, c.name as Car, o.name as Owner
FROM   Car_Owner as co INNER JOIN
       Cars as c ON co.id_car = c.id INNER JOIN
       Owner as o ON co.id_owner = o.id;
```

Но вопрос зачем вам делать такую таблицу, и не проще ли сразу сделать view

Comment: Тоже не вполне понимаю, зачем зачем банальный запрос на выборку владельцев машин с их машинами сохранять в виде постоянно хранящейся таблицы - но тут уж дело ТС (мы его задач не знаем).  А по теме - присоединяюсь к ответу выше.